# Bootstrap modal validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, validation, modal-dialog

I have a login modal which lets user (by href ) activate another modal adduser. The validation works fine for login modal but not for adduser modal.

Here's how I am calling the modals,

```
 <a data-toggle="modal" href="" data-target="#login">Login</a>

<div class="modal fade" id="login" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="login" aria-hidden="true">
```

```
<div class="modal fade" id="adduser" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="adduer" aria-hidden="true">
```

```
function AddUser()
{ 
    $('#login').modal('hide'); 
    $('#adduser').modal('show'); 
}

function BackToLogin()
{
    $('#adduser').modal('hide');
    $('#login').modal('show');
}
```

Validation code for login

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#login-form').validate({ 
        rules: { 
            email: { 
                required: true, 
                email: true 
            }, 
            agree: "required"
        }, 
        highlight: function(element) { 
            $(element).closest('.control-group').removeClass('success').‌addClass('error');
        },
        success: function(element) { 
            element.text('OK!').addClass('valid').closest('.control-group').removeClass('error').addClass('su‌​ccess'); 
        }
    }); 
});
```

Validation code for adduser

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#adduser-form').validate({ 
        rules: { 
            email: { 
                required: true, 
                email: true 
            }, 
            agree: "required"
        }, 
        highlight: function(element) { 
            $(element).closest('.control-group').removeClass('success').‌addClass('error');
        },
        success: function(element) { 
            element.text('OK!').addClass('valid').closest('.control-group').removeClass('error').addClass('su‌​ccess'); 
        }
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo on your adduser line.
You have: 
`<div class="modal fade" id="adduser" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="adduer" aria-hidden="true">`

Which should probably be:
`<div class="modal fade" id="adduser" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="adduser" aria-hidden="true">`

Comment: Sorry, but the problem is not resolved. I'm shure that I have to disable the first active modal (memory ?) before use the other one, but I dont know how. Something as like $("#login').validate().resetForm(); or remove

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand what your question is. After the user logs in, the adduser div shows and you want to have the user being added validated by the server? That's what your initial post leads me to believe. Are you having a user log in with one form, that form is then hidden and a new form in which you add a user shows up?

Comment: Hi, sorry for my bad english. My idea is that the user can start the modal adduer by that of login. If the user sends the empty, the validation will return messages specific to each field. Currently if I run the login and I try to send an empty form, I receive the validation error. But if I run adduser via login, the validation does not do anything at all.

Comment: Do you have validation code for login and adduser that you could add to your original post?

Comment: The only diffrents is the id_fome, here login.js validator                                  $(document).ready(function() {    $('#login-form').validate({
        rules: { email: {   required: true,  email: true  },
          agree: "required" },
        highlight: function(element) {
                $(element).closest('.control-group').removeClass('success').addClass('error');
        },   success: function(element) {
                element
                .text('OK!').addClass('valid')
                .closest('.control-group').removeClass('error').addClass('success'); }  }); });

Comment: Sorry for space, the editor can not recvie more than 585 cars

Comment: and here tha adduer

Comment: $(document).ready(function()
{
  $('#adduser-form').validate({
        rules: {
              email: {   required: true,   email: true  },
          agree: "required"
        },
highlight: function(element) {
                $(element).closest('.control-group').removeClass('success').addClass('error');
        },
        success: function(element) {
                element
                .text('OK!').addClass('valid')
                .closest('.control-group').removeClass('error').addClass('success');
        }  }); });